# Is there a better way to select multiple elements that have the same parent elements?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can simplify this selector, seeing as the parent elements are the same?

```
 $(".card .card-title .fa-star-o, .card .card-title .fa-star")
```

eg something like:

```
 $(".card .card-title (.fa-star-o, .fa-star)")
```

(above doesnt work, obviously)

The comma way does work of course, but I'm just wanting to know if there's a better, cleaner way.

Comment: You mean like this `$(".card .card-title").find(".fa-star-o, .fa-star").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});`

Comment: Yep. That'll do nicely. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it's

```
$(".card .card-title").find(".fa-star-o, .fa-star")
                      .css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```